# jQuery append in IE9 is for display only?

Tags: jquery, html, append

To illustrate more detail here.

I try to

```
$('.somediv').append("<div class='pagebreak'>xxx</div>")

.pagebreak{page-break-after: always; }
```

to give a pagebreak for html pages in printed version (ctrl+p).

However, the .pagebreak css only works in Firefox and chrome, but not ie(I tested it with ie9).
I found that the **xxx** text can successfully add in ie9. It means the append function can add code to .somediv actually, but the css of .pagebreak not works when I try to print it.

Is there anyway can solve it? 
Sorry for my poor English. Let me know if the question is not clear enough.

Comment: what do you mean by printed version?

Comment: are you using positions for .somediv.if so the page-break does not work inside position elements.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
I tried to directly insert <div class='pagebreak'>xxx</div> to source code, page-break works in ie9. But if I use .append to add <div class='pagebreak'>xxx</div>, nothing happen.